# Ошибка в KolourPaint: "Невозможно вставить содержимое в буфер обмена, поскольку оно имеет неподдерживаемый формат."

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль, администрирование

Работаю на ОС Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Столкнулся с проблемой при копировании изображения [отсюда](https://sun9-34.userapi.com/impg/SDfDfz-fzB89qjjU0bE04cmm1j4dWiD2vw68ag/VjAWSSDBjIg.jpg?size=2560x1920&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=120b1cbbb6d5d75ce2af5c9f47c93692&type=album).

Изображение либо вообще не копируется при нажатии ПКМ "Копировать изображение", либо копируется так, что при вставке в приложение KolourPaint выскакивает ошибка: `"Невозможно вставить содержимое в буфер обмена, поскольку оно имеет неподдерживаемый формат."`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с пободбным?

Answer (score 1):

> Кто-нибудь сталкивался с пободбным?

Я не знаю причины, но проблема воспроизводится. Попробовал с gimp - там без проблем. После этого сделал так:

1. Сохранил изображение на локальном диске.
2. Открыл его штатной гляделкой
3. Скопировал в буфер
4. Вставил в окно KolourPaint

Всё прошло без проблем:

[image: Окно программы KolourPaint]